# Query for results between now and 7 days from now

Tags: sql

I know there are similar answers to this, but none of them have worked for me.  I have a query with a date field in it.   I want to filter the results for the next 7 days.  It works if I specify the dates i.e date between `'2019-07-18' AND '2019-07-25'` but I need it to be more generic.

Thanks in advance!

Here are a few things I've tried:

```sql
CAST( datefield AS DATE ) > DATEADD( DAY, +7, CAST( GETDATE() AS DATE ))

WHERE GETDATE()+7

AND DATEADD(dd, -7, datefield) <= CAST(datefield AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use logic like this:

```
where datefield >= dateadd(day, 1, cast(getdate() as date)) and
      datefield < dateadd(day, 8, cast(getdate() as date))
```

This assumes you are using SQL Server (based on your syntax) and that you don't want today's data ("next 7 days").

Comment: Thank you!   This is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You didnt specify what SQL you are using so this might not be fine for you.

```
WHERE datefield BETWEEN SYSDATE AND SYSDATE + 7
```

Answer (score 0):

`datefield` between today and next 7 days

```
WHERE
     CAST(datefield AS DATE) <= DATEADD(DAY, 7, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE ))
 AND CAST(datefield AS DATE) >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE )
```